# Why using 'this' keyword gives a context?

Tags: java, android

I was using static `makeText()` function of `Toast` class in android studio.Now,as `makeText()` function requires an object of `Context` class ,what we can do is create an object of Context class by below given code.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

and use this `context` object as the parameter in `makeText()` function.That's OK.

But I was reading a book which used the `makeText()` function along with `show()` as below given code.

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Can you see me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android) page that `this` keyword can be used to get a `Context`.

So,my question is why using `this` keyword as a parameter of a static function of Toast class refers/gives/returns specifically a `Context` when `MyActivity`(from below code) class extends directly/indirectly `AppcompatActivity`,`FragmentActivity`,`Activity`,`ContextThemeWrapper`,`ContextWrapper` classes or why not 'this' keyword refers to an object of immediate class 'MyActivity' ?

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Bhai app chalu ho gai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.i("info","Done creating the app");
}
```

}

Comment: You should probably read some books about **basic** Java first. Seriously: android adds a whole lot layer of complexity; and you are definitely not ready for that when you don't understand what **this** is about.

Comment: Because `Activity` extends `Context` [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html)

Comment: @GhostCat This question is not a duplicate of the one it has been closed for. The OP is specifically asking about how `this` in `AppCompatActivity` can be passed to a method that takes `Context` parameter. This question is more about polymorphic substitutions and not about `this`. Please do spend some time understanding the semantics of the question before closing it. I urge you to open this question or find a more meaningful duplicate of it.

Comment: @Kartik `this` in `AppCompatActivity` refers to the current instance which is of type `AppCompatActivity`. Also, `AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of `Context` and can therefore be passed to a method that takes a `Context` as a parameter. This is one of the ways in which `Polymorphism` is used in the real world.

Comment: @CKing He writes: *I read on this page that this keyword can be used to get a Context.* ... I think he doesn't understand in the first place what *this* is about. I get your point; but I think duplicating to some polymorphism-explaining other question could as well be misleading. I dont mind when enough people come together to over-rule my close vote; but for now I will keep it as it is.

Comment: @CKing Does using `this` keyword creates more memory overheads than directly creating a `Context` object and using it as a parameter, because using an object of class which extends 5-6 classes directly/indirectly will have many functions and variables to create? ,also I think when you said that `this` refers to  `AppCompatActivity` ,I feel that it refers to `MyActivity` since it is more immediate class.

Comment: `this` means `myself`. When you say `myself`, you are not only `Kartik Watwani` StackOverflow user, but a human, a form of life as well. Same way Activity is a Context as well as Activity because it extends Context.

Comment: @GhostCat Fair enough and point taken.

Comment: @KartikWatwani Again: please read the question I duplicated to. Using *this* doesn't create an object at all. It is just a **reference** to an object that **already** exists. And: creating objects doesn't create "methods". An object is nothing more but some memory for the fields that belong to each object. The methods are part of the class loaded by the JVM; and there are tables will guide which method belongs where. So: again: you better study a lot of the java basics. First. Now.